# Transform 3D coordinates into joint rotations

Tags: python, animation, scripting

I have 3D body coordinates that i got using mediapipe pose and I want to know how to transform them into bone rotations so I can animate a 3D model in blender.

Here's the format of the mediapipe's keypoints :

```
{
    "Nose": {
        "x": 0.7359796166419983,
        "y": 0.2784487009048462,
        "z": -0.8704781532287598,
        "visibility": 0.9993504881858826
    },
    "Left Eye Inner": {
        "x": 0.7560076713562012,
        "y": 0.22832006216049194,
        "z": -0.8362604975700378,
        "visibility": 0.9988956451416016
    },
    "Left Eye": {
        "x": 0.766055703163147,
        "y": 0.22719711065292358,
        "z": -0.8365423083305359,
        "visibility": 0.9985707998275757
    },
    ...
}
```

This is how im creating the animation in blender

```
# Load 3D keypoints from JSON file
def load_keypoints(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        keypoints_data = json.load(f)
    return keypoints_data

# Animate 3D model in Blender
def animate_model(keypoints_data, frame_num):
    armature = bpy.data.objects['Armature']

    # Iterate through frames and set bone positions based on keypoints
    for joint in keypoints_data:
        bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame_num)
        bone = armature.pose.bones.get(joint)
        if bone:
            bone.location = (keypoints_data[joint]["x"] * 5, keypoints_data[joint]["y"] * 5, keypoints_data[joint]["z"] * 5)
            bone.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", index=-1)
 
 nb_files = next(os.walk('directory_path'))

 # Iterate over JSON files in the directory
 for frame_num in range(len(nb_files)):
     keypoints_data = load_keypoints('file' + frame_num + '.json')
     animate_model(keypoints_data, frame_num)
```